# subprocess error while installing aiohttp==3.8.1 and setproctitle==1.1.10 on mac

Tags: macos, subprocess, metadata, python-3.7, aiohttp

I am trying to run a local already done django project but I get this subprocess error while trying to install these to packages. I'm using python3.7 and my device is mac OS. These are the main errors:

1. Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error    2. Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully   3. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'    4.This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip    5. Encountered error while generating package metadata

notes: my pip is up to date, my venv is active, my python version is python 3.7.11

[upper part of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDxMD.png)
[end part of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DuOL.png)

I have searched all of errors mentioned above and read the document and installed the dependencies and requirements for these errors, but still get this subprocess error for those required packages!

I have also once deleted my virtual env and reinstalled my python3.7 and tried to install the packages again but it did not work.

This project is working well right now but I'm a django junior and I want to run this on my local machine so I can learn and practice the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/), aiohttp package only has support for `python  3.8, 3.9 and 3.10`. Your python version is 3.7 so you might want to use any of the python versions supported by it. The latest release is v 3.9.1 and should work well on any of the python versions already mentioned. You may look at the link for more information.

Comment: aiohttp 3.8 supported Python 3.7 though, so not sure what that installation error is.
Python 3.7 itself isn't even supported anymore, so certainly updating would be recommended regardless.